# Is it possible to send just a token via the MVVM Light Messenger?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I've been refactoring some code that was originally using the `Messenger` in MVVM Foundation to now use the `Messenger` in MVVM Light Toolit. One thing that I can't seem to find an equivalent for is the case where all you want to do is send a Token (i.e, the Token is acting as both a unique identifier for the message *and* the message itself).

**Original Code (MVVM Foundation)** - one string does it all

```
// send code
mvvmFoundationMessenger.NotifyColleagues("QuestionTimedOut");

// register code
mvvmFoundationMessenger.Register(
    "QuestionTimedOut",
    () => UpdateOnQuestionTimedOut());
```

**New Code (MVVM Light)** - is there a more elegant solution than this?

```
// send code
mvvmLightMessenger.Send("QuestionTimedOut", "QuestionTimedOut");

// register code
mvvmLightMessenger.Register<string>(
    this,
    "QuestionTimedOut",
    token => UpdateOnQuestionTimedOut());
```

---

I realize I could explicitly new up a `NotificationMessage` but that would add even more code.

Comment: So is next version ready? I'm doing the exact same thing from MVVM Foundation to MVVM Light!

Comment: @Dimitris, so far, this isn't fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good point. I put that on the backlog for MVVM Light VNext.

Answer (score 0):

You could derive from MvvmLight's `Messenger` and add your own convenience methods or you could add `Messenger` [Extension Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) in an extension class.